# Call Dispose() on a WindowsIdentity object? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose, windows-identity

I am retrieving a WindowsIdentity object by calling:

```
win_id = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

with the intention of getting the currently logged on user name, which works fine.

WindowsIdentity implements IDisposable, but since I din't create the object myself, do I still need to call .Dispose() on it when I am finished with it or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` returns an instance, so you should properly dispose it.

Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0.aspx):

> Returns a WindowsIdentity  object that
>   represents the current Windows user.

And [here](http://www.themissingdocs.net/wordpress/?p=64) is another nice article regarding this topic:

> WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() returns an instance which you should dispose, 
>   otherwise you temporarily leak a user handle.

Comment: That second article has very important context you don't link: "Unless you impersonate". Apparently that can result in difficult to track down errors.